# "Тыкать", "выкать", "нукать", а от "мы" (личного местоимения) как?

Tags: словообразование

ну - нукать;

ты - тыкать;

вы - выкать,

мы - ?

[4:54](https://www.google.com/search?source=hp&q=%D0%A7%D0%B0%D1%81%20%D0%9F%D0%B8%D0%BA%201994)

Answer (score 4):

Глагол **мыкать** упоминается в статье [Словообразовательная структура делокутивов в современном русском языке](https://cyberleninka.ru/article/v/slovoobrazovatelnaya-struktura-delokutivov-v-sovremennom-russkom-yazyke) (Н. А. Николина, Ю. А. Светашова):
Формально делокутивы могут мотивироваться и местоимениями (*товокать, якать, **мыкать**, выкать*), частицами (*воткать*), существительными (*мамкать, мадамкать*), формулами речевого этикета (*мерсикать*)…

В словарях глагол не представлен, но в произведениях слова от "мы" встречаются.

*– Ты это **мыканье** брось. Нет никаких «мы», есть «я» и «ты». И вообще, не стой над душой.

…

– Я кому сказал: хватит **мыкать**!*
(А. Моравиа. Я и Он)

Answer (score 0):

Pluralis majestatis (Королевское «мы»), глагольная форма, полагаю, отсутствует.